# Why does spring-cloud-config not expand properties for spring-boot-actuator?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-config

I have spring-boot-actuator and spring-cloud-config set up.  I have various properties set similar to the following:

```
info.app.name=@project.name@
info.app.version=@project.version@
```

If I put those properties in the application.properties, then I get:

```
{
  "app" : {
    "name" : "project-name",
    "version" : "1.2.3",
<more is ommitted>
```

But if I put it spring-cloud-config, I get the following:

```
{
  "app" : {
    "name" : "@project.name@",
    "version" : "@project.version@",
<more is ommitted>
```

I don't understand why this is the case since I expected config to serve it and actuator to expand it. Is this a bug?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolution of `@project.name@` and `@project.version@` in `application.properties` is [performed at build time](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-automatic-expansion), not at runtime. So when your application runs, `application.properties` in the jar file contains:

```
info.app.name=project-name
info.app.version=1.2.3
```

There is nothing in Spring Boot or Spring Cloud Config that will resolve placeholders like `@project.name@` at runtime, so when those properties are pulled from Config Server you will get the literal values for the properties.